# conflicting types for main and previous definition of main was here when compiling with make

Tags: c, makefile

I'm trying to compile three files together, having one main method in passweb.c.

heres passweb.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cipher.c>
#include <menu.c>

long pointer;
char *createRecord(char *name, char *password, char *type);
char *file = "password.csv";
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(fopen(file,"r")==NULL){
        FILE *newFile = fopen(file,"w+");
        fclose(newFile);
    }
    if(strcmp(argv[0],"-menu")==1){
        menu();
    }
    else if(strcmp(argv[0],"-add")==1){
        add(argv[1], argv[2], argv[3]);
    }
    else if(strcmp(argv[0],"-edit")==1){
        edit(argv[1],argv[2],argv[3],argv[4],argv[5],argv[6]);
    }
}
```

and cipher.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int Encrypt(char *fileName){
    int offset=5;
    Shift(fileName, offset);
}
int Decrypt(char *fileName){
    int offset=-5;
    Shift(fileName, offset);
}
```

the makefile:

```
passweb: passweb.c menu.c cipher.c
      gcc -o passweb passweb.c menu.c cipher.c -I.
```

the errors:

```
passweb.c:10: error: conflicting types for ‘main’
./cipher.c:3: error: previous definition of ‘main’ was here
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. 
Thank you in advance for your time!!

Comment: What does `menu.c` look like? Does it define `main` as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't include source files into source files. Get rid of the following:

```
#include <cipher.c>
#include <menu.c>
```

The way you've written it, you're compiling menu.c and cipher.c twice. First when you compile passweb.c, and again when you compile menu.c and cipher.c.

Comment: how could I change my makefile instead?

Comment: You could remove menu.c and cipher.c from the compile command line, but that's not a good way to do it.